# Where to place .bib file when saving many documents in dropbox

Tags: bibliographies

I have acquired the habit of saving my documents directly in dropbox, and I attempt to use one big bibliographyfile to call upon for many of these documents. I make a folder for each document, and for the document to compile I need a copy of the bibliography file in the folder. What happens is that I some times save new items in the folder's copy of the bibliographyfile, but that saving is not counted in the master copy of the bibliography which I keep one level above the folders for the documents. Some times I therefore end up with bibliographies that are not updated properly.

Is there a way to manage these matters more effectively while saving directly in drop.box?

Comment: You could symlink the file in Dropbox to a place that is already in the search path. For me that would be in `~/texmf/bibtex/bib/. Thus, although the file there is the one being used, you only need to update the file in Dropbox.

Comment: I use a small batch script that concatenate all my bib files, it's simple one but I don't mind sharing if you want it!

Answer (score 1):

\addbibresource{../references/database.bib}

would give you a common database in a folder (called references) at the same level as your documents in windows -- for example.

Making a lot of assumptions e.g. that you are using biblatex.